# Simple External hack for Assault Cube gone wrong?

Tags: c++

So I'm following a Youtube tutorial on making a simple external hack for Assault Cube.
I reach part 6 of the tutorial and... blam. My compiler is giving me the error:

> [Error] expected declaration before '}' token

So I add that. And it just repeats.
I'm using Orwells Dev C++ and have NO idea where I've gone wrong.
Harsh criticism welcome, including those "you're jumping too ahead of yourself. Try something more simple." etc etc

```
// Youtube Console Trainer Tutorial -- Trainer for Assault Cube
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

std::string GameName = "AssaultCube";
LPCSTR LGameWindow = "AssaultCube";
std::string GameStatus;

bool IsGameAvail;
bool UpdateOnNextRun;

//Ammo Variables
bool AmmoStatus;
BYTE AmmoValue[] = {0xA3, 0X1C, 0X0, 0X0};
DWORD AmmoBaseAddress = {0x004DF73C};
DWORD AmmoOffsets[] = {0x378, 0x14, 0x0};

//Health Variables
bool HealthStatus;
BYTE HealthValue[] = {0x39, 0X5, 0X0, 0X0};
DWORD HealthBaseAddress = {0x004DF73C};
DWORD HealthOffsets[] = {0xF4};

int main()
{
HWND hGameWindow = NULL;
int timeSinceLastUpdate = clock();
int GameAvailTMR = clock();
int onePressTMR = clock();
DWORD dwProcID = NULL;
HANDLE hProcHandle = NULL;
UpdateOnNextRun = true;
std::string sAmmoStatus = "OFF";
std::string sHealthStatus = "OFF";

while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT))
{
    if(clock() - GameAvailTMR > 100)
    {
        GameAvailTMR = clock();
        IsGameAvail = false;

        hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL,LGameWindow);
        if (hGameWindow)
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcID);
            if(dwProcID != 0);
            {
                hProcHandle =     
                   OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,         FALSE, dwProcID);
                if(hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hProcHandle == NULL )
                {
                    GameStatus = "Failed to open process for valid handle";

                }
                else{
                    GameStatus = "AssaultCube Ready To Hack";
                    IsGameAvail = true;
                }

                else{
                    GameStatus = "Failed to get process ID";

                }

                else {
                    GameStatus = "AssaultCube NOT FOUND";
                }


                if(UpdateOnNextRun || clock() - timeSinceLastUpdate > 5000 )

                    system("cls");
                    std::cout << "-------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
                    std::cout << "      AssaultCube memory hacker" << std::endl;std::endl;
                    std::cout << "-------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
                    std::cout << "GAME STATUS:" << GameStatus << std::endl << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "[F1] Unlimited Ammo -> " << sAmmoStatus << " <- " << std::endl << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "[F2] Unlimited Health -> " << sHealthStatus << " <- " << std::endl << std::endl;
                }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Here's a screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/UXSjlzV.png

Comment: if(dwProcID != 0);   <-- this semicolon shouldn't be there

Comment: doesnt fix it.
it's a problem with the indentation around the else statements, but idk what.

Comment: True, the presence of the semicolon wouldn't cause the compile error you are seeing (rather it would cause the code immediately after it to always be executed rather than only when dwProcID is not equal to zero).  The problem with the braces is that they aren't matched; it has nothing to do with indentation, since C/C++ doesn't care about whitespace.  Most editors have a "match braces" function that let you move the cursor from the brace it is on to its counterpart; that's very useful for tracking down what braces aren't matching.  E.g. in vi you position the cursor on a brace and press %

Comment: The extra `}` outside the code formatting block at the end is pure win.

Comment: Considering the existence of statements like `…; std::endl;`, whoever wrote this in the first place wasn't sufficently familiar with C++.

Comment: The tutorial you followed is ancient, there are much better ones available, for anyone looking at this

Answer (score 1):

A missing { here:

```
if(UpdateOnNextRun || clock() - timeSinceLastUpdate > 5000 )
```

And after the line with `GameStatus = "AssaultCube Ready To Hack";` there are two other `else` without `if`. Remove/comment them.

And next time, better indentation!

Comment: And that didn't fix it.

Comment: @Aegis Updated. Remove the two `else`s after the ` GameStatus = "AssaultCube Ready To Hack";`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `else` clauses are nested, when they should be outside their respective `if` clauses. Let's shuffle some braces around:

```
hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL,LGameWindow);
if (hGameWindow)
{
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcID);
    if(dwProcID != 0);
    {
        hProcHandle =     
           OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,         FALSE, dwProcID);
        if(hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hProcHandle == NULL )
        {
            GameStatus = "Failed to open process for valid handle";

        }
        else{
            GameStatus = "AssaultCube Ready To Hack";
            IsGameAvail = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        GameStatus = "Failed to get process ID";

    }
}
else {
    GameStatus = "AssaultCube NOT FOUND";
}


if(UpdateOnNextRun || clock() - timeSinceLastUpdate > 5000 )
{
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "      AssaultCube memory hacker" << std::endl;std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "GAME STATUS:" << GameStatus << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[F1] Unlimited Ammo -> " << sAmmoStatus << " <- " << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[F2] Unlimited Health -> " << sHealthStatus << " <- " << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcID);
if(dwProcID != 0);
{
```

it should be:

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcId);
if(dwProcID != 0);
{
```

it's a little d. in dwProcID